# Broken connection reason

Tags: glassfish, connection-pooling, h2

I'm testing my Spring MVC web-app with Apache JMeter,but I have some troubles with h2db pool connection.

My test consists on 5 threads and 100 loops. I test registration flow on glassfish server. 
Firstly as a database connection class I used `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`, but my connections was suspended  in the middle of test. Now, I use DBCP with following parameters:

```
<property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
<property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
```

Unfortunately tests are still suspended. I'm getting:

```
  org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Broken connection: "session closed"
Connection is broken: "session closed" [90067-164]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
  at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.checkClosed(SessionRemote.java:500)
  at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.removeServer(SessionRemote.java:431)
  at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:80)
  at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.<init>(CommandRemote.java:46)
  at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:437)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1125)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollbackInternal(JdbcConnection.java:1427)
  at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:467)
  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368)
  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:323)
  at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
  at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:597)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:845)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:411)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
  at $Proxy137.save(Unknown Source)
  at com.car.rental.controllers.user.RegisterFormController.processSubmit(RegisterFormController.java:95)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
  at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
  at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
  at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
  at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
  at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
  at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
  at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
  at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It shows that there's some troubles with transaction rollback. My register form params contain one image file (34,7 kB). Shouldn't such files be used during performance tests?

Anyone knows the reason or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be database system error/bug. When I started the same application with MySQL everything is OK.